# Double submit a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can i double submit a form . 
a way i have ; `<form action="action.php" method="POST">`
and in the same time i have an other **"action.js"** file in where i use Ajax to submit the form ?

**action.php** contains :

```
<?php
//CODE
?>
```

and **action.js** contains :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var contact = $("#contact").val();
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
        if(name=='')
        {
            alert("");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ...why would you want to double-submit a form? For what purpose?

Comment: For example , i want to make a js file to make a log for the activities of the user.

Comment: I still don't understand how submitting a form twice helps accomplish that. User tracking can be accomplished in a thousand ways, and I don't think I've ever heard of "double form submission" being one of them.

Comment: @arthurakay I needed to do this once with an email signup form. I needed to send the results to the CMS, and to the Email Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just submit both with ajax?

Remove the "action" from the  `<form>`, and with JavaScript prevent the form from submitting, then run the first ajax request, then the second, then if necessary, you can use JS to redirect the user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function secondAjax(dataString){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                //optionally redirect the user
                window.location('http://someurl.com')
            }
        });        
    }


    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var contact = $("#contact").val();
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
        if(name=='')
        {
            alert("");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    //send second ajax call
                    secondAjax(dataString); // pass the dataString into the new function
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That's good , but is there any other way to do it with both files ? php and ajax ? if not that will be good enough

Comment: yes, you could initially preventDefault, then in the ajax call Success function you can trigger for the form to be submitted in a way that bypasses the preventDefault and instead just submits it the regular way. But I've had problems when trying to do things like that in the past, the first method I showed is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

What about if your page re-directs to action.php when submitted, and add code in the action.php file which will log user activities once its loaded or after its original function has been executed.

If you're using databases, why not use your MySQL trigger function for the logging, that way you don't need to run any scripting, but all is done automatically, if your triggers are set up correctly.

Here's a link to some examples of [MySQL Triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/how-to-log-logon-logoff-and-user-activity-on-mysql-server-for-audit)

Comment: That's not enough if i want to analytics and i want to submit data to an email and other to database , + i want that doesn't make a lot of time loading , and doesn't charge so much the server .